# Difference in netinet/tcp.h Vs linux/tcp.h

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am trying to use the TCP option `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` which was added to linux in `2.6.37`.

Apprently my `C` source includes the `netinet/tcp.h` instead of `linux/tcp.h`. And `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` is defined in `linux/tcp.h` and not in `netinet/tcp.h` I read [here](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=6202) that user space apps should NOT include any header from `linux/` (like in this case `linux/tcp.h`). But that link doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is incorrect, and a bulletin board is hardly a definitive source.

You should not include header files from the `linux` directory unless you are trying to include linux specific functions which are only to be found by including header files from the linux directory.

In relation to `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT`, the [man-page for TCP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) notes in respect of many of the options *'This option should not be used in code intended to be portable'*. Whilst it does not note this in respect of `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT`, it is a linux-only option as far as I understand it.

However, in this case:

```
$ grep -r TCP_USER_TIMEOUT /usr/include
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:#define TCP_USER_TIMEOUT  18 /* How long for loss retry before timeout */
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:#define TCP_USER_TIMEOUT   18  /* How long for loss retry before timeout */
```

at least in my include files, it's present in *both* files. Perhaps you need to update your includes.

Comment: Thanks, I checked, indeed these files need updating.